# What are the most active communities (2018) for dapp developers?

Tags: dapp-development, dapps

I'm trying to determine if there are community hubs (forums, chats, etc) that most dapp developers use and they can't live without. Where do they hang around to get involved in discussions, learn, stay up-to-date, etc?

Answer (score 1):

I like to use **gitter**, more specifically the Nethereum, Ethereum, Solidity, Raiden and similar ones. Else, I'd suggest you to explore **linkedin** and **reddit**, a lot of things going around there, just try search for your preferred keywords.